# HAProxy how to permanently stick on clientid

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I need all incoming requests be assigned based on their clientid to a certain backend server. For this we have a luascript that extracts clientid and is used to be assigned on. But in reality I can see that very often(during 2 hours) that many clientids are switched to another backend server.

Example:

```
0x5620407589c0: key=6a5063eb-2477-4a27-a1ab-e904d1cc85af use=0 exp=0 server_id=1 conn_cur=0 server_name=server1
```

could be transferred during 2 hrs from server1 to server2

```
0x5620407589c0: key=6a5063eb-2477-4a27-a1ab-e904d1cc85af use=0 exp=0 server_id=2 conn_cur=0 server_name=server2
```

I need sort of 'eternal' stick table but at the same to balance across backend servers and to have as less as possible such 'switches' of incoming requests with same clientid.

Haproxy config:

```
global
    lua-load /usr/share/haproxy/mqtt.lua
frontend main
    tcp-request inspect-delay 10s
    tcp-request content lua.getid
    default_backend edges

backend edges
    balance leastconn
    stick-table type string len 128 size 100k nopurge store conn_cur
    stick on var(txn.clientid)
    tcp-request content track-sc0 src

    server server0 ip0 maxconn 1950 slowstart 600s check ssl verify none
    server server1 ip1 maxconn 1950 slowstart 600s check ssl verify none
    server server2 ip3 maxconn 1950 slowstart 600s check ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not a solution, but maybe a nudge in a good direction. Maybe someone can improve the answer basing on this.
Your stick-table doesn't declare `expire`, but [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.2/configuration.html#4-stick-table) says you should when using `nopurge`. Also in example you show entries with `exp=0`, which is looks expired. I'm not sure whether such entry is used or overwritten. My guess is your clients get redispatched due to entry expiration.
Another idea is servers going down for a while, health checks failing. You can check status page for uptime or logs for information about servers going up/down. Also experiment with `option noredispatch` or `force-persist`.

I would recommend to consider investing in second haproxy instance and configuring `peers` so that haproxy could load state of the table from peer when you reboot haproxy's host and provide persistence in case of reboot.